# Calculate multiple values ​in a loop

Tags: javascript, calculation

In a future income calculator, I need to display the data accumulated in 5 years, 10 years and 15 years.

In this account, I take the value of the monthly contributions, after 12 months, I apply the annual profitability, with that the final value of one year is concluded.

To get the value of the second year, I take the initial value of the sum of the 12 months and make the sum with the value of the 12 months with profitability.

The account is as follows ...

```
contributions = 536,06;
profitability = 4.27;
fixedYearVal = 536,06 * 12; // 6.432,72
profitabilityVal =  (profitability / 100) * fixedYearVal;
fixedYearprofitability = fixedYearVal + profitabilityVal;
```

With that, I discover the first year with profitability.
The value for the second year will be (secondYear = fixedYearVal + fixedYearprofitability).
The final amount for the second year will be

```
percentSecondYear = (profitability / 100) * secondYear;
finalSecondYear = percentSecondYear + secondYear;
```

And the value of the third year is going to be

```
thirYear = finalSecondYear + fixedYearVal;
percentthirdYear = (profitability / 100) * thirYear;
finalThirdyear = percentthirdYear + thirYear;
```

Anyway, as I said, I need it for 5 years, 10 years and 15 years, and I can't imagine any other way than to make thousands of lines, I thought about doing it with a for in **Javascript** but with this data boo I found myself lost .

Comment: use a function,  number of years is input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw something together. Maybe this can help you get started. The idea is 1) set some base values 2) throw it through a loop of n years you want to calculate. 3) return the final results in an array so you can see a year by year

```
// Calculate the next year
const caclNextYear = (lastYear, fixedYearVal, profitability) => {
  const nextYr = lastYear + fixedYearVal;
  const percentSecondYear = (profitability / 100) * nextYr;
  const finalYr = percentSecondYear + nextYr;
  return finalYr;
};

// Calc years by number of years
const estimateByYears = (years) => {
  const contributions = 536.06;
  const profitability = 4.27;
  const fixedYearVal = 536.06 * 12; // 6.432,72
  const profitabilityVal =  (profitability / 100) * fixedYearVal;
  const fixedYearprofitability = fixedYearVal + profitabilityVal;
  const yearByYear = [fixedYearprofitability];

  for (let i = 1; i < years; i++) {
    let lastYr = yearByYear[yearByYear.length - 1];
    yearByYear.push(caclNextYear(lastYr, fixedYearVal, profitability));
  }
  
  return yearByYear;
};

// Call
const yearByYear = estimateByYears(5);
// yearByYear : [6707.397144, 13701.200146048799, 20993.63853628508, 28597.46404578445, 36525.97290453945
console.log('yearByYear', yearByYear);
```